# Function mocked by spyOn, still getting called actual implementation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am writing a unit test for a component.

there is one function in component which i want to mock,which is getting call in OnInit.

I have mocked that function like below

```
  spyOn(component, 'functionToMock');
```

but still that function get called in OnInit and my unit test getting failed.

Mock is not working here using spyOn ...any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell much without seeing the code, but it sounds like the oninit runs **before** the test.

It is a good practice to isolate the test from the component life cycle. We can safely assume OnInit runs when it needs to.

Instead, mock the method in a `beforeEach` block, and execute it explicitly at the test.